# I need to create a controller class to implement a method that will create an object that inherits from an abstract class

Tags: arraylist, controller

I don't know how to explain this very well but I'll try. I am tasked with making a controller class that has a method called createSphere which will create a sphere object and then add it to my arraylist. Here are my classes

Sphere class

```
public class Sphere extends ThreeDShape {

private double radius;
private double surfaceArea;
private double volume;

public Sphere(int x, int y, int z, double radius) {
    super(x, y, z);
    this.radius = radius;
}

public double getRadius() {
    return this.radius;
}


public boolean equals(ThreeDShape aShape) {
    Sphere aSphere = new Sphere(1, 2, 3, 5);
    return aSphere.equals(aShape);
}

public String toString() {
    return "This sphere has a radius of: " + this.radius + " and is located at ("
            + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + ", " + this.getZ() + ")";
}

@Override
public double getSurfaceArea() {
    return this.surfaceArea;
}

@Override
public double getVolume() {
    return this.volume;
}

}
```

Class that has the arraylist

```
public class ShapeManager {


private ArrayList<ThreeDShape> shapes;

public ShapeManager() {
    this.shapes = new ArrayList<ThreeDShape>();
}

public void addShape(ThreeDShape newShape) {
    this.shapes.add(newShape);
}

public void addSphere(Sphere newSphere) {
    this.shapes.add(newSphere);
}

public ArrayList<ThreeDShape> getShapes() {
    return this.shapes;
}

public String toString() {
    if (this.shapes.size() < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot have less that zero items in arraylist");
    }

    String results = "";
    for (ThreeDShape aShape : this.shapes) {
        results += aShape.toString();
    }
    return results;
}
}
```

and finally the controller class that I don't know what to do with

```
import edu.westga.cs1302.project03.model.ShapeManager;

public class ShapeController {

private ShapeManager manager = new ShapeManager();

public void createSphere(int x, int y, int z, double radius) {
    // TODO : code
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I have understood your question.
If you just have to add a sphere to your arrayList using the Controller class this should be enough:

```
public void createSphere(int x, int y, int z, double radius) {
    this.manager.addSphere(new Sphere(x,y,z,radius));
```

}

Comment: It worked, thanks man! I don't know why I couldn't understand that.